# How to check if input in a float value has been left empty?

Tags: c#

I'm creating a program which collects some personal info and persons' salary to calculate their earnings after tax.
I'm using a switch statement for the menu. Which looks like this:

```
Get a person’s details (p)
Get the Salary (s)
Calculate and display (d)
Exit (x)
```

I want the users to complete these in a sequential order, so before entering their salary or trying to calculate their pay, they are forced to enter their details. e.g.: Full name is the first personal detail that they have to fill in.
At this point the users has selected (d) to display their earnings, but they will be stopped because they haven't filled in their personal details.

```
Console.WriteLine("\nUser selected to calculate and display their earnings\n");
if (full_name == "")
{
    Console.WriteLine("Error: Please enter personal details before attempting to display your pay\n");
    break;
}
```

This works fine because it's a string, so if it has been left empty, they return to the original menu.

But I also want to stop them from trying to select option (d) if they haven't filled in option (s), their salary, which is stored in a float. If I try this:

```
if (annual_salary == null)
{break;}
```

it says that it will always be false since a value of type float is never equal to null of type float.

This is my while loop for option (s) which collects the data when the user selects this option.

```
while (valid == false)  
{
    Console.Write("Enter your annual salary: > ");
    vtemp = Console.ReadLine();
    // Validate the data entered
    if (vtemp == "")
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nError : Annual salary cannot be empty. Please try again...\n");
    }
    else
    // Check if data is a valid integer
    returnVal = float.TryParse(vtemp, out annual_salary);
    if (returnVal == false)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\nError : Please enter numbers only. Please try again...\n");
    }
    else
    // Check value is positive
    if (i < 0)
    {
       Console.WriteLine("\nError : Annual salary must be positive. Please try again...\n");
    }
    else
    {
        valid = true;
        break;
    }
}// End while
```

But if the users never select (s) and decide to go straight to (d) after filling in (p), They will get an incorrect value from the output.

So to clarify: How do I check if a float value has been left empty or skipped?

Comment: What is wrong exactly with your current implementation?  It looks like you are checking for an empty input (though you could use `if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(temp)`), and it looks like you are checking for a parse failure.

Comment: So everything's fine, unless the user decides to skip the (s) option, because i don't want someone to be able to calculate their pay if they havn't put in their annual salary. It's just that the annual_salary is a float, so it can't be checked like a string can.

Comment: You already have a `valid` variable, why not check that on entry to the (d) option.

Answer (score 0):

Simplest solution will be to give your `s` a default negative value, and make sure it's not negative before you continue.

Depending on how / where you're enforcing this, you can do different things. If you're doing a WPF or other GUI development, you can disable the button until it's all set.
If you want to do it in logic, you can go with the above solution, or have some flags that will be set to true when you select an option, and you will only continue if all flags are set to true, and so one.

---

Edit:
I've updated `p` to `s`. It's the same really. When he hits `d` either check that `s` is not negative (you can initialize it to -1), or if you go with the flag option, make sure the flag for it is true (it's set when you hit `s` for example).
Then, if you have all input, calculate, otherwise write a message saying he needs to input salary.

Comment: Yea it's just that i've already got p covered, as the user can't fill in their salary if they havn't put in their full_name, which is the first requirement in (p). But the user could just fill in (p) and then skip straight to (d) which is calculating the pay, but without the salary value (s).
And it's just a console application.

Comment: Yea thanks i get what you mean, but where am i initialising it? Because they way i have it set up is in a switch with cases, and the user can only input p/s/d/x(quit), any other input is just given an error of unknown selection. So what am i setting as -1?

Comment: either where you define the variable that will hold it, or in the constructor